# Retrieve Internet Explorer cookie by InternetGetCookie API

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, cookies

I read IE cookie by InternetGetCookie API but just permanent cookie retrieved. I need to Retrieve all cookie (permanent and session cookie).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384710(v=vs.85).aspx):

> To retrieve cookies, it checks for
>   both session cookies and persistent
>   cookies. Session cookies, which do not
>   have an expiration date, are stored in
>   memory and are available only to the
>   process in which they were created.